# Returning distinct values from foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, distinct, echo

I have a foreach loop which `echo`'s each of the property types in my search results. The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
    foreach($search_results as $filter_result) {
        echo $filter_result['property_type'];
    } 
?>
```

The above code returns:

```
house house house house flat flat flat
```

I would like to do something similar to the MySQL 'distinct', but I am not sure how to do it on a foreach statement.

I want the above code to return:

- house
- flat

Not repeat every item each time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with:

```
$property_types = array();
foreach($search_results_unique as $filter_result){
    if ( in_array($filter_result['property_type'], $property_types) ) {
        continue;
    }
    $property_types[] = $filter_result['property_type'];
    echo $filter_result['property_type'];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Example:

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input); 
print_r($result);

Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

You will need to alter it slightly to check using the `property_type` part of your array.

Comment: Please note that `array_unique` does not behave as expected if your values are not strings or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use two loops here. One to build an array of distinct `property_type` fields (you can use code in the loop to check the item doesn't already exist).

Then, use a second loop to step through the array and `echo` the list of items.

Comment: second loop is unnecessary as you could just print or obsolete the current record if found/not found in the array

Comment: True - although this would be handy if you wanted to preserve the array for later use rather than only printing to screen as you go.

Comment: also true :) choose whatever is needed, although one-loop will be marginally faster

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep track of already echoed values or build a new unique array of the values of all the **$filter_result['property_type']**. But that would then require you to iterate over that array once more to actually print. So keeping track would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking there was some parameter to the in_array() function to get the count of the items found.

But is doesn't exist.

So try with [array_unique()](http://%22http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

The better way is to duplicate the array before the `foreach` loop and apply this function.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 

$filter=array();
foreach($search_results as $filter_result)
   $filter[]=$filter_result['property_type'];
$filter=array_unique($filter);

print_r($filter);
?>
```

Comment: I don't like this one really, besides the fact that the distinction should be done when fetching the data, you blindly add it to an array just to use array_unique on it. Thats adding another symptom fix in my opinion.

Comment: @WesleyvanOpdorp You trade RAM for CPU: The `array_unique()` version is much faster, but needs more RAM, but the `in_array()` version is much slower, while using less RAM. In the OQ there were only 6 rows, which makes the additional RAM of `array_unique()` a no brainer IMHO